# Xamarin Studio 4.0.13 , Subversion and Mavericks is this combination broken

Tags: svn, xamarin, xcode5, osx-mavericks

I have just upgraded to Mavericks (and XCode 5.0).
And I have lost the ability to use subversion from with in Xamarin Studio.

I have installed the latest XCode commandline tools (doing this in the passed did fix similar issues).

Interestingly I an use subversion in XCode.

Is there something I am doing wrong or is this combination of tools incompatible

Regards Christian Stœr Andersen

ps Mavericks also broke my ASIO interface rendering my recording tools useless.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue and already has an entry in Xamarin's Bugzilla:

[Bug 15610](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=15610)